Searching in a subset of records seems not working
we are planning to do some 2 step ANN search with 2 kinds of embeddings; word embedding, multimodal embedding.
The scenario is described as the following image.
During the test, search with condition of filter=f"id in {subset_of_ids}" seems not working.
As I understand, the filtering logic applied before actual searching (pre-filtering), but the result returns empty list. Am I missing something?

